get protobuf over-the-wire size in bytes
is there a way in java to get the size of a protobuf in bytes? I know there exists the getSerializedSize function, but I don't know if thats an accurate representation of what gets sent over the wire. Is there a way to get that size?


I don't know if thats an accurate representation of what gets sent over the wire

Serialization is converting the proto into bytes that are sent over the wire or stored in a file.  The serialized size is the size in bytes.  Yes, this is an accurate representation of what gets sent over the wire.

If you want to calculate the size of the serialized message in a more manual way or check its accuracy, you can serialize the message to a byte array and then get the size of that byte array
byte[] serializedMessage = message.toByteArray();
int sizeInBytes = serializedMessage.length;

This approach essentially serializes the message and then measures the size of the resulting byte array, which should be equivalent to the value returned by getSerializedSize().
